# Visual Basic 2010 Log in Error on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Details:   **Visual Studio**,  **Visual Basic 2010**,  **Microsoft SQL Server 2008**,   Connection String:

```
    MyCn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;     AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\tcogensan.mdf; " & _
      "MultipleActiveResultSets=True; User Instance=True;Integrated Security=SSPI; Trusted_Connection=True"

    MyCn.Open()
```

SQL Server Login Details

> - Server Type: Database Engine,
> - Server Name: USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS,
> - Authentication: Windows Authentication,
> - User Name: User-PC\User, Password:

**Problem:**

Everytime I access my database I get a `Cannot open user default database. Login failed. Login failed for user 'User-PC\User'.` on the *MyCn.Open()* Line of code. I`ve been on this for days. Please help. 
The details on the error is error number 4064.

I have uploaded error

Image Files:
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-MK2llmBacxdnIxaWV1ZGtzR1E/view?usp=sharing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the database specified as a default for your SQL Server login does not exist. Connect to your Express instance with some other tool and check the result of this query:

```
select sp.name, sp.default_database_name
from sys.server_principals sp
where sp.name = 'User-PC\User';
```

If it points to a non-existent database, switch it to `master` by executing a corresponding `alter login` statement.

Comment: I did a query on *Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio* after execution Results are name: User-PC\User default_database_name: tcogensan.  **tcogensan** is my database. My database exist.

Comment: @Learner, it exists only after you have attached it. At the moment connection is made, it does not exist. I know of no other way to receive this particular error.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I`m really new and this is my first project involving SQL Server. I forgot to mention that If I Run Visual Studio as Administrator there would be no error, problem with this arrangement is that once the project is published I could no longer connect to the database.

Comment: I have already switch the default database to Master. Error still exist.

Comment: Are the developer and publishing SQL Server instances the same, or different? Is it the same user account that is used to connect to SQL Server after publishing? Does it have sufficient permissions? What about its default database?

Comment: GOT IT!!! I check the security properties of the .mdf file, 'User-PC\User' was not part of the Group or user names so I added it then gave Full Control. EUREKA... error no longer exist.  @Roger Wolf Thanks man.

Comment: Wow. Never thought one needs file system permissions to attach a database. Though the user account under which SQL Server service is running definitely needs them, that's right.